# startActivity() does nothing even when the Intent is specified correctly

Tags: android, android-activity, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, start-activity

I am trying to open an activity from the launcher activity when an FCM-generated notification gets clicked. The startActivity function does nothing even when the log statement written above gets executed. Following are some relevant files/functions, please tell why is the ConversationDetailActivity not starting:

**The function which starts another activity from LoginActivity**

```
void handleNotificationClick()
{
    if (getIntent().getExtras() != null)
    {
        for (String key : getIntent().getExtras().keySet())
        {
            Object value = getIntent().getExtras().get(key);
            System.out.println("----- pushNotif Key: " + key + " Value: " + value);
        }

        Intent intent;

        if(getIntent().getStringExtra(Master.KEY_PUSH_NOTIFICATION_CATEGORY).equals(Master.KEY_PUSH_NOTIFICATION_CONVERSATION))
        {
            intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ConversationDetailActivity.class);
        }
        else
        {
            intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ApprovalDetailActivity.class);
            if(getIntent().getStringExtra(Master.KEY_PUSH_NOTIFICATION_APPROVAL_TYPE).equals("I"))
                intent.putExtra(Master.KEY_WHICH_APPROVAL, Master.KEY_VERIFICATIONS);
            else if(getIntent().getStringExtra(Master.KEY_PUSH_NOTIFICATION_APPROVAL_TYPE).equals("A"))
                intent.putExtra(Master.KEY_WHICH_APPROVAL, Master.KEY_APPROVALS);
            else
                intent.putExtra(Master.KEY_WHICH_APPROVAL, Master.KEY_COMPLETED);

            intent.putExtra(Master.KEY_IS_FROM_CONVERSATION, false);
        }
        intent.putExtra(Master.KEY_PUSH_NOTIFICATION_POST_ID , getIntent().getStringExtra(Master.KEY_PUSH_NOTIFICATION_POST_ID));
        intent.putExtra(Master.KEY_IS_FROM_PUSH_NOTIFICATION, true);
        intent.putExtra(Master.KEY_POSITION, 0);

        System.out.println("----- starting new activity from handleNotificationClick");
        LoginActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
        LoginActivity.this.finish();
    }
}
```

**The sendNotification function from which the notification is generated**

```
private void sendNotification(String messageBody)
    {
        Intent intent;
        System.out.println("----message body: " + messageBody);
        if(notificationBundle.getCategory().equalsIgnoreCase(Master.KEY_PUSH_NOTIFICATION_CONVERSATION))
        {
            intent = new Intent(this, ConversationDetailActivity.class);
        }
        else
        {
            intent = new Intent(this, ApprovalDetailActivity.class);
            if(notificationBundle.getApprovalType().equals("I"))
                intent.putExtra(Master.KEY_WHICH_APPROVAL, Master.KEY_VERIFICATIONS);
            else if(notificationBundle.getApprovalType().equals("A"))
                intent.putExtra(Master.KEY_WHICH_APPROVAL, Master.KEY_APPROVALS);
            else
                intent.putExtra(Master.KEY_WHICH_APPROVAL, Master.KEY_COMPLETED);

            intent.putExtra(Master.KEY_IS_FROM_CONVERSATION, false);
        }

        intent.putExtra(Master.KEY_PUSH_NOTIFICATION_POST_ID , notificationBundle.getPostID());
        intent.putExtra(Master.KEY_IS_FROM_PUSH_NOTIFICATION, true);
        intent.putExtra(Master.KEY_POSITION, 0);

        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT | PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.mnet_icon)
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        int random = (int) ((new Date().getTime() / 1000L) % Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        notificationManager.notify(random, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.vishesh.test">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:name=".MnetApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/mnet_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.LoginActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

        <activity
            android:name=".activities.ConversationDetailActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_conversation_detail"
            android:parentActivityName=".activities.MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name=".activities.ConversationDetailActivity" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="http" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="mnet.mediaware.com.m_net.activities.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.ApprovalDetailActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_approval_detail"
            android:parentActivityName=".activities.MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="mnet.mediaware.com.m_net.activities.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.NewConversationActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_new_conversation"
            android:parentActivityName=".activities.MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="mnet.mediaware.com.m_net.activities.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.NotificationActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_notification"
            android:parentActivityName=".activities.MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="mnet.mediaware.com.m_net.activities.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.ProfileActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_profile"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:parentActivityName=".activities.MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="mnet.mediaware.com.m_net.activities.MainActivity" />
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".utils.firebase.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service
            android:name=".utils.firebase.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding ***android:exported="true"*** to the activity in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: No change. The issue still persists.

Answer (score 0):

First finish Login activity, and then call start activity.

```
LoginActivity.this.finish();
LoginActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: No change. The issue still persists.

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest, define your class which you want to open like this

```
  <activity
        android:name=".activities.ApprovalDetailActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>


    </activity>
```

Comment: No change. It didn't help.

Answer (score -1):

**Nothing works for me except this one.** The thing work for me is simple. Make sure you add this in the activity that you want to open directly.

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="MainActivity" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
```

And from the push notification you must add a new payload: **click_action**
it will looks like this -

```
"notification": {
  "title": "hello",
  "body": "test message",
  "click_action": "MAIN_ACTIVITY"
},
```

> Note: You can name it as you want **MAIN_ACTIVITY** but must be same in both place.