# Notification click not opening specific activity when the app is in background/not running

Tags: android, android-intent, push-notification, android-pendingintent, start-activity

Someone asked almost the same question before. But Unfortunately, I am not getting any type of help from the comments and answers. I don't also have enough points to comment.

Of course Using `flag PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` not working at all.

Here is the existing question link: [Not opening specific activity on notification click when the app is in background/not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40804803/not-opening-specific-activity-on-notification-click-when-the-app-is-in-backgroun)

**Please take a look into the question to get a better understanding.**

I want to include some more points:

1. If my app is in the background and I simply click on a notification, is it a general scenario of not being open my specified activity?
2. I can solve this either using a set of bundle into the launcher activity or using a local broadcast (if you are already in your app running and then tap on a notification). But is there any other way?

Thank you very much for your time and assistance in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer after a long research and ofcourse you may visit the top level reference site [TaskStackBuilder Usage and Definition](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.html)

Please don't overlook the awesome video into the above link.

Comment: Can you post your solution?